# Converting current signal to voltage signal with a resistor

Tags: voltage, resistors

sorry if this is dumb but I can't seem to wrap my head around something.

I am reading a book and in the book this exercise was :

Given a controller with analog output (control signal) in the range 0 — 20
mA. Suppose the controller is to be used to control a device (e.g. a pump)
that only takes voltage in the range 0 — 10 V. How can you (easily) convert
the current control signal to a corresponding voltage control signal. Draw
your solution.

and I figured:
[image: My solution(guess)]
but the solution was:

[image: Soloution according to the book]

Why is my "guess" wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A voltage differential exists *across* a resistance. Your circuit doesn't convert the current into a voltage, it converts it into a voltage *difference*, i.e. the device end could be as much as 10V lower than the controller end.

If you want to have a voltage instead then you need to have the other end connected to the supply return, leading to the circuit in the solution.

Comment: Ok, so in my guess the 10 volt is just across my resistor, so I don't really know if I send 10 v signal to to the pump, only that I send a signal with 10v difference from my previous signal. And in the book the difference is for the entire curcuit, so I know that the difference from + to - is 10 v, for the pump, the resistor and the controller?

Comment: Yes, that's what KVL says.

Answer (score -1):

When you put the resistor in series with the "Device", the current to voltage ratio is determined by the sum of the resistor and the internal resistance of the "device".  Most voltage measurement systems have a very high resistance, which would totally skew the current to voltage conversion ratio.

With the correct solution, the two resistances end up in parallel minimizing the impact of the internal resistance of the Device.

Series resistors: Rtotal = R1 + R2
Parallel resistors: Rtotal = 1 / ( (1 / R1) + (1 / R2))